# Is the sequence $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \sqrt[n]{n} $ absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I tried the root test but it doesn't help me I think: 
$ \left | \sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}} \right | \equiv  \left | n^{\frac{1}{n}^{\frac{1}{n}}} \right | $

And also the ratio test isnt very helpful here. Any ideas?

Comment: The terms don't converge to $0$.

Comment: What is $\sqrt[0]{0}$? ($0$, I presume.) ¶ Note that not even $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ln \sqrt[n]{n}$ is convergent.

Comment: @fragant. You edit your question after some participants answered. I'll downvote your OP

Comment: Where's the edit?  I don't see any edit history...

Comment: I had some mistakes in the question but I edited before somebody answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is false. Let $a_{n}=n$. We have $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}=1+\frac{1}{n}\rightarrow1.$$
Remember that if $\lim\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=L$ then $\lim\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=L$. Therefore $$\lim\sqrt[n]{a_{n}}=\lim\sqrt[n]{n}=1.$$
Thus $\displaystyle\Sigma_{n=0}^{\infty}\sqrt[n]{n}$ can not converge.

Comment: Sorry edit was accidentally

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}}=n^{1/n^2}$. But $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^{1/n^2}=1\neq 0$, so $\{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt[n]{n}}\}$ can't be summable.

Then, the series is not absolute convergent (indeed, it is not convergent because it is a series with positive terms)

Comment: Certainly we have divergence. But the Root Test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt[n]{n}>1$ for $n>1$, so $\sqrt[n]{n}$ doesn't tend to zero. Hence, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sqrt[n]{n}$ cannot converge, let alone converge absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing it in the format: $x^\frac{1}{x}$ and differentiate it from there using the log and exponential functions.